# CPU bugs in Ubuntu 22 on Imac Late 2009

Tags: 22.04, cpu, mac, nvidia-geforce

I need some help bringing a late 2009 Imac from the dead, I managed to install Ubuntu 22.04 (I'm new to the OS), and fixed Nvidia card problems, then I runned the cpu info and found this information:

```
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority vpid dtherm

vmx flags   : vnmi flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr vapic

bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit mmio_unknown
```

I would like to know how to solve the bugs or what can I do. Here is the complete cpu information in case its needed;

```
processor   : 0

vendor_id   : GenuineIntel

cpu family  : 6

model       : 23

model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7600  @ 3.06GHz

stepping    : 10

microcode   : 0xa0b

cpu MHz     : 2445.269

cache size  : 3072 KB

physical id : 0

siblings    : 2

core id     : 0

cpu cores   : 2

apicid      : 0

initial apicid  : 0

fpu     : yes

fpu_exception   : yes

cpuid level : 13

wp      : yes

flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority vpid dtherm

vmx flags   : vnmi flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr vapic

bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit mmio_unknown

bogomips    : 6102.73

clflush size    : 64

cache_alignment : 64

address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual

power management:

processor   : 1

vendor_id   : GenuineIntel

cpu family  : 6

model       : 23

model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7600  @ 3.06GHz

stepping    : 10

microcode   : 0xa0b

cpu MHz     : 2456.741

cache size  : 3072 KB

physical id : 0

siblings    : 2

core id     : 1

cpu cores   : 2

apicid      : 1

initial apicid  : 1

fpu     : yes

fpu_exception   : yes

cpuid level : 13

wp      : yes

flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 
clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority vpid dtherm

vmx flags   : vnmi flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr vapic

bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit mmio_unknown

bogomips    : 6102.73

clflush size    : 64

cache_alignment : 64

address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual

power management:
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You mention bugs, but on my much more recent Lenovo Thinkpad I have the exact same line after "bugs".

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 22 desktop release.

Comment: Please be precise with details; 22 & 22.04 are different Ubuntu products (Ubuntu Core 22 being a *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server; the different *year* format being used to highlight it's a *snap* only product; where *year.month* is used for *deb* based that can also use *snap* packages). You mention both; where desktop packages are not built for *year* or the 22 product (only 22.04 & 22.10)

Answer (score 2):

These are not software bugs that have to be "solved". These are CPU hardware bugs that are already addressed by Linux kernel.

If you run `lscpu`, you'll see something like

```
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         Not affected
  L1tf:                  Not affected
  Mds:                   Not affected
  Meltdown:              Not affected
  Mmio stale data:       Not affected
  Retbleed:              Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Not affected
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Retpolines, STIBP disabled, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

Anyway there is nothing that a user can do.